# check multiple tsv file and drop all the same rows from each tsv in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, compare

i have three tsv files.

file 1:

```
1   Alice   24      
10  Bill    23
4   Ellen   24
9   Mike    30
```

file 2:

```
6  Julie   76
2  Bob     42
7  Tom     54
5  Frank   30
1  Alice   24
```

file 3:

```
3  Dave    68
8  Jerry   34
1  Alice   24
5  Frank   30
2  Bob     42
```

OUTPUT:
My desire output is to drop all the rows in which first and second column's values are the same from any of those tsv files and keep other rows as it is.

file 1:

```
10  Bill    23
9   Mike    30
4   Ellen   24
```

file 2:

```
6  Julie   76
7  Tom     54
```

file 3:

```
3  Dave    68
8  Jerry   34
```

And my tsv files are headless. I have tried following code so far.

```
with open('file2.tsv') as check_file:
    check_set = set([row.split('\t')[0].strip().upper() for row in check_file])

with open('file1.tsv', 'r') as in_file, open('file3.tsv', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if line.split('\t')[0].strip().upper() in check_set:
            out_file.write(line)
```

But i didnot got my desired three output files with this code. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have TSV files, I would assume they are TAB separated (not comma). You should try `.split('\t')`

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please reconsider and then answer it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to read all your TSV files and count each occurrence of the first two columns. Python's [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections%20counter#collections.Counter) can be used for this (which is based on a dictionary).

Whilst reading each row in, save it in a `data` dictionary where the keys are the filenames and the contents are lists of the first two values along with the raw rows. A [`defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections%20defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) is used to avoid having to add an entry if it doesn't already exist before appending a new entry.

After reading everything in, `counts` can now be used to determine if any given row has been seen only once, other values can be skipped over.

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

counts = Counter()      # hold counts of each first two value pairs
data = defaultdict(list)  # hold all data from all files

for tsv in ['file1.tsv', 'file2.tsv', 'file3.tsv']:
    with open(tsv) as f_tsv:
        for row in f_tsv:
            split = list(map(str.strip, row.split('\t')))
            key = tuple(split[:2])  # first and second column values
            counts[key] += 1
            data[tsv].append((key, row))

for tsv, key_rows in data.items():
    with open('x' + tsv, 'w') as f_tsv:
        for key, row in key_rows:
            if counts[key] == 1:
                f_tsv.write(row)
```

I would recommend you add `print()` statements to better understand what each of the variables holds, e.g. `print(counts)` and `print(data)`

Note: take out the `'x' +` when ready, this was added to write the output files to slightly different filenames to avoid overwriting the original files whilst testing.

Comment: thank you so much. got output as expected.